# How can I zoom 3 elements to a different size while hovering over their parent element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to perform a zoom on hover for 3 elements with each element taking a different parameter.

Here's my html code:

```
<section id="features">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-check-circle feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

So what I'm trying to achieve here is when you hover over the parent div "feature-box", the "feature-box-img" should increase its size to 3rem, `<h3>` should increase its font-size to 3.5 rem and `<p>` should increase its font-size to 1.5rem.

So Basically these 3 elements should take 3 different parameters at the same time once you hover over the parent div "feature-box".

Is it possible to achieve this using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `parent:hover > child`.

```css
.feature-box:hover > .feature-box-img {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.feature-box:hover > h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.feature-box:hover > p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
      <span class="fas fa-check-circle feature-box-img"></span>
      <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
      <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
      <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
      <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
      <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
      <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
      <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
      <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

example hover with animation

```css
.feature-box, h3, p {
   transition: .5s;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.row .feature-box:hover > .feature-box-img {
   font-size: 3rem;
}

.row .feature-box:hover > p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.row .feature-box:hover > h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-check-circle feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 feature-box">
        <span class="fas fa-bullseye feature-box-img"></span>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you intend as the "size" of "feature-box-img". If you intend the height and width then, being an inline element, you will have to set a display "inline-block" or "block" on it as you can't set width nor height on an inline element.

Back to your question, you can use CSS pseudoclass ":hover" to write styles that will kick in when "feature-box" is being hovered.

```
.feature-box-img {
  /* so you can set width and height */
  display: block;
  /* for visualization as it has no content in this example */
  background: red;
  /* default height and width */
  height: 2px;
  width: 2px;
}

/* styles to apply to feature-box children when it hovered */
.feature-box:hover .feature-box-img {
  /* when "feature-box" parent is hovered increase width, size and font-size */
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.feature-box:hover h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem
}

.feature-box:hover p {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}
```

A link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/Qausim/pen/YzqqLJP